# Why is beta-mercaptoethanol often added to cell culture media

Tags: cell-culture

Many protocols suggest that beta-mercaptoethanol is necessary for growing cells. It is a reducing agent but what does it mechanistically do for your cells. When would one not add it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2-me is a reducing agent necessary to be added to help keep free radical oxygen from affecting mouse cells.  It is generally not necessary for human cells.

Also from [S Bannai](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/1467329) and [Ishii et al.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/3680392), 2-mercaptoethanol improves tumor cell uptake of cystine by creating a reducing environment.

Comment: BTW, the statement about human cells is not true. The addition of bME to primary immune cell cultures, especially B and T cell cultures, is common.

Comment: Common doesn't necessarily mean necessary.

Comment: I have never used it in human B and T cell culture. I'm switching to mouse work for my post doc and trying to figure out all the differences. Thanks for this post!